# Three JS: get progress of multiple file load

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, loading, gltf

I am new to Three JS.

What i am trying to do here is to create a loading screen which should show the progress of assets being loaded required for a scene.

I have multiple type of assets (7 files in total) e.g. -

1. 4 GLB files
2. 2 Texture files
3. And 1 Obj file

Now from the Three JS docs i can load file like the following (Obviously i will need different loaders based on file type) -

```
const gltfLoder: EThree.GLTFLoader = new Three.GLTFLoader(this.loadingManager);
            gltfLoder.load("/res/three/models/gltf/multiple/cat.glb", (glb: Three.GLTF) => {
                console.log("THREE >> GLB Loaded ", glb);
            }, (xhr: any) => {
console.log ("loading progress >> " + xhr.loaded);
}
```

This will give me progress of a single file, is there a solution where I can get load progress of all files? i.e. the 100% progress should be when all 7 files are loaded.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoadingManager has onProgress. eg

```
this.loadingManager.onProgress = function ( url, itemsLoaded, itemsTotal ) {
    console.log( 'Loading file: ' + url + '.\nLoaded ' + itemsLoaded + ' of ' + itemsTotal + ' files.' );
};
```

There is also `onStart`, `onLoad`, `onError`.

[LoadingManager reference](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager)

Comment: What if I have one single file with a size of 20MB? How could I show bytes loaded for `TextureLoader` Class by may or may not using `LoadingManager`, since it is called onload of file and not onprogress